# Using sudo gives me the error: Sorry, try again

Tags: sudo

This is what happens when I try :

```
sudo gedit

[sudo] password for casper: 
Sorry, try again.
```

My username is casper.

I seem to be in the sudo group :

```
id | grep sudo
uid=1000(casper) gid=1000(casper) 
groups=1000(casper),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),12 6(sambashare)
```

Auth log looks like this :

```
tail /var/log/auth.log
May 16 18:39:18 casper-pc pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened 
for user root by (uid=1000)
May 16 18:39:18 casper-pc pkexec[2426]: casper: Executing command [USER=root] 
[TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/casper] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package- 
system-locked]
May 16 18:42:16 casper-pc pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened 
for user root by (uid=1000)
May 16 18:42:16 casper-pc pkexec[5463]: casper: Executing command [USER=root] 
[TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/casper] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package- 
system-locked]
May 16 18:45:16 casper-pc pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened 
for user root by (uid=1000)
May 16 18:45:16 casper-pc pkexec[7356]: casper: Executing command [USER=root] 
[TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/casper] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package- 
system-locked]
May 16 18:46:55 casper-pc sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; 
logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=casper rhost=  user=casper
May 16 18:47:00 casper-pc sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
May 16 18:47:00 casper-pc sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify 
password for [casper]
May 16 18:47:00 casper-pc sudo:   casper : 1 incorrect password attempt ; 
TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/casper ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/gedit
```

Could someone please help me restore `sudo`? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your sudo is working fine. You are inputing the wrong password for sudo by the looks of it. Did you put a different password for root on your install?

Comment: Can it be that you accidentally switched to some other keyboard layout?

Comment: No, but I figured it out. Thanks. I had to remove the sudo package and reinstall it using synaptic package manager.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `sudo` package.
You will surely have to remove the `sudo` package and reinstall it using the `synaptic package manager`.

Hope this can be helpful for you.

---

**NB**: Corrected using OP's comment.

Comment: How would you create a new user if you forgot your password?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, how is he executing those other commands? Does the issue he is facing prevent him from logging into the system? I don't think so. :)

Comment: He might have autologin enabled...

Comment: No, but I figured it out. Thanks. I had to remove the sudo package and reinstall it using synaptic package manager.

Comment: @SHIVAMKUMAR the answer has been revised to reflect what worked for you... You could accept it if you wish. Thanks.